# What is the maximum capacity of the Eleth Mixer?

Tags: tales-of-graces-f

As you use the Eleth Mixer it gains experience and increases it's capacity. What is the maximum amount of Eleth it can possibly hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can eventually hold 9999 Eleth at one time. You can only increase the Eleth capacity by cooking food during battle.